# Calculate number of (distinct/unique) times a person has entered a building per day

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, pandas-groupby, pivot-table

Trying to count distinct number of times a person entered a facility on each day.

What I've achieved: Distinct entries by the person for the four columns.

```
df = pd.read_excel("Sample.xlsx)
df1 = df.groupby(['Date', 'Facility'], as_index=False)['By_Name'].nunique()
df2 = df.groupby(['Date', 'Facility'], as_index=False)['Preceptor'].nunique()
df3 = df.groupby(['Date', 'Facility'], as_index=False)['Preceptee'].nunique()
df4 = df.groupby(['Date', 'Facility'], as_index=False)['Circulator'].nunique()
```

**Where I'm struggling:** Checking if that person already entered the facility

**Sample Input** (Sample.xlsx) of a given day [actual data is for every day of the month]:

| Date | Facility | Begin Time | By Name | Preceptor | Preceptee | Circulator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-10 | Betsy House | 14:50 | DS |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | Betsy House | 15:30 | DS |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | Betsy House | 18:20 | DS |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | Brian South | 13:10 | DS |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | Camden Place | 18:10 | NP |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 10:01 | DI |  |  | KL |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 10:31 | DI |  |  | KL |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 10:36 | DI |  |  | KL |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 11:58 | DI |  |  | KL |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 12:11 | DI |  |  | KL |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 12:56 | DI |  |  | KL |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 13:35 | DI |  |  | KL |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 17:30 | DI |  |  | KL |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 09:50 | KL |  |  | DI |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 10:47 | KL |  |  | DI |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 11:14 | KL |  |  | DI |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 16:18 | KL |  |  | DI |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 16:34 | KL |  |  | DI |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 18:09 | KL |  |  | DI |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 18:20 | KL |  |  | DI |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 09:30 | LOA |  |  | WH |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 09:48 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 11:03 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 12:10 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 13:10 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 13:34 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 13:55 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 16:19 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 16:19 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 16:43 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 16:43 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 17:09 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 11:52 | WH |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | Capital Center | 11:45 | DS |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | CHH | 17:09 | AA |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | Chatham | 15:47 | RB |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | Chatham | 17:25 | RB |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | CIH | 09:48 | MP |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | CRHS | 16:15 |  | WH | LOA |  |
| 2021-09-10 | CRHS | 16:15 |  | WH | LOA |  |
| 2021-09-10 | HRMC | 13:29 | MP |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | HRMC | 14:01 | MP |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | HRMC | 15:35 | MP |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | IMH | 09:50 | LD |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | IMH | 11:15 | LD |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | IMH | 18:30 | LD |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | IMH | 19:40 | LD |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | MUSC | 11:20 | CT |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | MUSC | 11:50 | CT |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | MUSC | 12:50 | CT |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | MUSC | 13:43 | CT |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | MUSC | 14:55 | CT |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | MUSC | 15:40 | CT |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | MUSC | 16:09 | CT |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | MUSC | 16:20 | CT |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | MUSC | 16:38 | CT |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | NCSH | 10:20 | NP |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | NCN | 17:40 | EK |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | Oak Forest | 10:50 | RB |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | Oak Forest | 11:50 | RB |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | PRC | 13:05 | LD |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | PMH | 15:15 | NP |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | SSHD | 11:50 | NP |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | SSHD | 12:00 | NP |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | SSHD | 12:20 | NP |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | SSHG | 13:44 | RB |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | SCC | 11:36 | MP |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | SCC | 17:55 | MP |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | SHD | 11:00 | LB |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | SHD | 13:10 | LB |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | SHD | 15:00 | LB |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | SHD | 16:10 | LB |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | SHM | 09:45 | LJ |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | SHM | 11:30 | LJ |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | SHM | 11:50 | LJ |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | SHM | 12:11 | LJ |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | SHM | 12:25 | LJ |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | SHM | 16:50 | LJ |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | VEH | 11:40 | AA |  |  |  |

**Required Output** (By Facility)

| Date | Facility | Entries | Begin Time | By Name | Preceptor | Preceptee | Circulator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-10 | Betsy House | 1 | 14:50 | DS |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | Brian South | 1 | 13:10 | DS |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | Camden Place | 1 | 18:10 | NP |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | Capital Center | 1 | 11:45 | DS |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | CHH | 1 | 17:09 | AA |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | Chatham | 1 | 15:47 | RB |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | CIH | 1 | 09:48 | MP |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | CRHS | 2 | 16:15 |  | WH | LOA |  |
| 2021-09-10 | HRMC | 1 | 13:29 | MP |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | IMH | 2 | 09:50 | LD |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | IMH |  | 18:30 | LD |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | MUSC | 1 | 11:20 | CT |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | NCSH | 1 | 10:20 | NP |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | NCN | 1 | 17:40 | EK |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | Oak Forest | 1 | 10:50 | RB |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | PRC | 1 | 13:05 | LD |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | PMH | 1 | 15:15 | NP |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | SSHD | 1 | 11:50 | NP |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | SSHG | 1 | 13:44 | RB |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | SCC | 2 | 11:36 | MP |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | SCC |  | 17:55 | MP |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | SHD | 1 | 11:00 | LB |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | SHM | 1 | 09:45 | LJ |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | VEH | 1 | 11:40 | AA |  |  |  |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 6 | 09:30 | LOA |  |  | WH |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear |  | 09:48 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear |  | 09:50 | KL |  |  | DI |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear |  | 10:01 | DI |  |  | KL |

Any and all help will be appreciated. TIA

Comment: Countifs(), set criteria to include, or exclude ie ignore, as needed: ID, Facility, Time etc

Comment: Why is Entries sometimes empty? Eg the second SCC

Comment: @user2246849 in the output file? Because it's showing the total number on the first line and then giving a detail of all the incidents that have led to that total.

Comment: @SolarMike Maybe Unable to drill down to details using Countifs(). It's excluding results when I try to remove values that have already been counted in "By Name".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: get first occurrence and ignore if in any other column on same day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72274023/pandas-get-first-occurrence-and-ignore-if-in-any-other-column-on-same-day)

Comment: @GinoMempin yes, it does.