# Pandas: get first occurrence and ignore if in any other column on same day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Newbee here.

Given the below files, I am trying to count how many times a distinct value occurs. The data is for multiple facilities for each day so stuck how to get the correct totals.

Tried using nunique in combination with groupby but not able to get the logic.

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Date', 'Facility'], as_index=False)['By_Name'].nunique()
```

**Sample Input** (Sample.xlsx) of a given day [actual data is for every day of the month]:

| Date | Facility | Begin Time | By Name | Preceptor | Preceptee | Circulator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 10:01 | DI |  |  | KL |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 10:31 | DI |  |  | KL |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 10:36 | DI |  |  | KL |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 11:58 | DI |  |  | KL |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 12:11 | DI |  |  | KL |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 12:56 | DI |  |  | KL |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 13:35 | DI |  |  | KL |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 17:30 | DI |  |  | KL |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 09:50 | KL |  |  | DI |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 10:47 | KL |  |  | DI |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 11:14 | KL |  |  | DI |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 16:18 | KL |  |  | DI |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 16:34 | KL |  |  | DI |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 18:09 | KL |  |  | DI |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 18:20 | KL |  |  | DI |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 09:30 | LOA |  |  | WH |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 09:48 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 11:03 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 12:10 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 13:10 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 13:34 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 13:55 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 16:19 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 16:19 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 16:43 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 16:43 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 17:09 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 11:52 | WH |  |  |  |

**Desired Output** (By Facility)

| Date | Facility | Entries | Begin Time | By Name | Preceptor | Preceptee | Circulator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear | 6 | 09:30 | LOA |  |  | WH |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear |  | 09:48 | SR |  |  | JR |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear |  | 09:50 | KL |  |  | DI |
| 2021-09-10 | Cape Fear |  | 10:01 | DI |  |  | KL |

Any and all help will be appreciated. TIA

Comment: you need to use .count and not nunique, could you provide your data in a pd.DataFrame please

Comment: *but not able to get the logic*, does groupby and nunique output what you want?

Comment: @DataSciRookie .count gives me a total of all the non NaN values. I am looking for only the first distinct occurrence. As for the data in pd.DataFrame, I am trying to paste it here but it isn't getting formatted properly.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh groupby and nunique give me part of the solution. I get the correct count for each of the four columns but then I need to exclude the count if it's already occured. Ex: "DI" has already entered the facility in "By Name" so his count shouldn't be updated when he comes up again in "Circulator"

Comment: @GonçaloPeres This is almost there but what I'm struggling with still remains to be done. If a person has entered the facility, it is counted as 1 entry (As you can see in the desired output). So total number of Entries should be 6 for cape fear.

Comment: @GonçaloPeres Yes. And "Perceptor" and "Perceptee". They are empty for this facility but may not be so for other facilities/dates.

Comment: @GonçaloPeres it will be the same as "By Name" or "Circulator". Let's say it's "AA" in "Preceptor" and XX in "Preceptee" in row 1 and 5 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

Based on clarifications by OP in comments, here is a new strategy to get what is required:

```py
df = df.set_index(['Date', 'Facility', 'Begin Time']).stack()
df.index=df.index.droplevel(3)
df = df.to_frame().rename(columns={0:'Name'}).reset_index()
df2 = df.groupby(['Date', 'Facility'])['Name'].nunique().to_frame().rename(columns={'Name': 'Entries'})
indexCols = ['Date', 'Facility', 'Entries']
df = df.join(df2, on=['Date', 'Facility']).reindex(columns=indexCols + list(set(df.columns) - set(indexCols)))
df = df.assign(TEMP_COL=0).groupby(indexCols + ['Name']).nth(0).drop(columns='TEMP_COL')
```

Explanation:

- Using `Date, Facility, Begin Time` as the index, call `stack()` to rearrange the four columns containing names into a single column with the old column name indicating "Kind of Name" (`By Name, Preceptor, Preceptee` or `Circulator`) added as level of the row multiindex.
- Drop the "Kind of Name" level (level 3) from the row multiindex.
- Rename column `0` to be `Name`, call `reset_index()` to move `Date, Facility, Begin Time` out of the row multiindex and back into column labels.
- Use `groupby()` and `nunique()` to calculate `Entries`: the number of unique names (across all four original columns) associated with each `Date, Facility`.
- Use `join()` to add an `Entries` column to the original dataframe.
- Use `groupby()` on `Date, Facility, Name`, then use `nth(0)` to get the first row of each group (including its `Begin Time`), also using a dummy column `TEMP_COL` to make sure we don't run out of columns when performing the `groupby()`.

**Example 1** (using original input from the question):

Output:

```
                                  Begin Time
Date       Facility  Entries Name
2021-09-10 Cape Fear 6       DI        10:01
                             JR        09:48
                             KL        10:01
                             LOA       09:30
                             SR        09:48
                             WH        09:30
```

**Example 2** (adds a second `Facility`):

```
          Date      Facility Begin Time By Name  Preceptor  Preceptee Circulator
0   2021-09-11  Facility Two      10:01      AA       <NA>       <NA>         ZZ
1   2021-09-11  Facility Two      10:31      AA       <NA>       <NA>         ZZ
2   2021-09-11  Facility Two      10:36      AA       <NA>       <NA>         ZZ
3   2021-09-11  Facility Two      11:58      DI       <NA>       <NA>         KL
4   2021-09-11  Facility Two      12:11      DI       <NA>       <NA>         KL
5   2021-09-11  Facility Two      12:56      DI       <NA>       <NA>         KL
6   2021-09-11  Facility Two      13:35      DI       <NA>       <NA>         KL
7   2021-09-10     Cape Fear      10:01      DI       <NA>       <NA>         KL
8   2021-09-10     Cape Fear      10:31      DI       <NA>       <NA>         KL
9   2021-09-10     Cape Fear      10:36      DI       <NA>       <NA>         KL
10  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      11:58      DI       <NA>       <NA>         KL
11  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      12:11      DI       <NA>       <NA>         KL
12  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      12:56      DI       <NA>       <NA>         KL
13  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      13:35      DI       <NA>       <NA>         KL
14  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      17:30      DI       <NA>       <NA>         KL
15  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      09:50      KL       <NA>       <NA>         DI
16  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      10:47      KL       <NA>       <NA>         DI
17  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      11:14      KL       <NA>       <NA>         DI
18  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      16:18      KL       <NA>       <NA>         DI
19  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      16:34      KL       <NA>       <NA>         DI
20  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      18:09      KL       <NA>       <NA>         DI
21  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      18:20      KL       <NA>       <NA>         DI
22  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      09:30     LOA       <NA>       <NA>         WH
23  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      09:48      SR       <NA>       <NA>         JR
24  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      11:03      SR       <NA>       <NA>         JR
25  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      12:10      SR       <NA>       <NA>         JR
26  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      13:10      SR       <NA>       <NA>         JR
27  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      13:34      SR       <NA>       <NA>         JR
28  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      13:55      SR       <NA>       <NA>         JR
29  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      16:19      SR       <NA>       <NA>         JR
30  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      16:19      SR       <NA>       <NA>         JR
31  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      16:43      SR       <NA>       <NA>         JR
32  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      16:43      SR       <NA>       <NA>         JR
33  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      17:09      SR       <NA>       <NA>         JR
34  2021-09-10     Cape Fear      11:52      WH       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
```

Output:

```
2021-09-10 Cape Fear    6       DI        10:01
                                JR        09:48
                                KL        10:01
                                LOA       09:30
                                SR        09:48
                                WH        09:30
2021-09-11 Facility Two 4       AA        10:01
                                DI        11:58
                                KL        11:58
                                ZZ        10:01
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Here's a way to get something close to what your question shows as desired output:

```py
df1 = df.groupby(['Date', 'Facility'], as_index=False)['By Name'].nunique().rename(columns={'By Name': 'Entries'}).set_index(['Date', 'Facility'])
df2 = df[['Date', 'Facility', 'By Name']].join(df1, on=['Date', 'Facility'])

df = df.assign(Entries=df2['Entries']).reindex(columns=['Date', 'Facility', 'Entries'] + [col for col in df.columns if col not in ['Date', 'Facility']])
df = df.groupby(['Date', 'Facility', 'Entries', 'By Name']).nth(0)
```

---

**Example 1 (uses the original input in the question):**

```
          Date   Facility Begin Time By Name  Preceptor  Preceptee Circulator
0   2021-09-10  Cape Fear      10:01      DI       <NA>       <NA>         KL
1   2021-09-10  Cape Fear      10:31      DI       <NA>       <NA>         KL
2   2021-09-10  Cape Fear      10:36      DI       <NA>       <NA>         KL
3   2021-09-10  Cape Fear      11:58      DI       <NA>       <NA>         KL
4   2021-09-10  Cape Fear      12:11      DI       <NA>       <NA>         KL
5   2021-09-10  Cape Fear      12:56      DI       <NA>       <NA>         KL
6   2021-09-10  Cape Fear      13:35      DI       <NA>       <NA>         KL
7   2021-09-10  Cape Fear      17:30      DI       <NA>       <NA>         KL
8   2021-09-10  Cape Fear      09:50      KL       <NA>       <NA>         DI
9   2021-09-10  Cape Fear      10:47      KL       <NA>       <NA>         DI
10  2021-09-10  Cape Fear      11:14      KL       <NA>       <NA>         DI
11  2021-09-10  Cape Fear      16:18      KL       <NA>       <NA>         DI
12  2021-09-10  Cape Fear      16:34      KL       <NA>       <NA>         DI
13  2021-09-10  Cape Fear      18:09      KL       <NA>       <NA>         DI
14  2021-09-10  Cape Fear      18:20      KL       <NA>       <NA>         DI
15  2021-09-10  Cape Fear      09:30     LOA       <NA>       <NA>         WH
16  2021-09-10  Cape Fear      09:48      SR       <NA>       <NA>         JR
17  2021-09-10  Cape Fear      11:03      SR       <NA>       <NA>         JR
18  2021-09-10  Cape Fear      12:10      SR       <NA>       <NA>         JR
19  2021-09-10  Cape Fear      13:10      SR       <NA>       <NA>         JR
20  2021-09-10  Cape Fear      13:34      SR       <NA>       <NA>         JR
21  2021-09-10  Cape Fear      13:55      SR       <NA>       <NA>         JR
22  2021-09-10  Cape Fear      16:19      SR       <NA>       <NA>         JR
23  2021-09-10  Cape Fear      16:19      SR       <NA>       <NA>         JR
24  2021-09-10  Cape Fear      16:43      SR       <NA>       <NA>         JR
25  2021-09-10  Cape Fear      16:43      SR       <NA>       <NA>         JR
26  2021-09-10  Cape Fear      17:09      SR       <NA>       <NA>         JR
27  2021-09-10  Cape Fear      11:52      WH       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
```

Output:

```
                                     Begin Time  Preceptor  Preceptee Circulator
Date       Facility  Entries By Name
2021-09-10 Cape Fear 5       DI           10:01       <NA>       <NA>         KL
                             KL           09:50       <NA>       <NA>         DI
                             LOA          09:30       <NA>       <NA>         WH
                             SR           09:48       <NA>       <NA>         JR
                             WH           11:52       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
```

**Example 2 (adds a second `Facility`):**
(see UPDATED ANSWER above for sample input.)
Output:

```
                                        Begin Time  Preceptor  Preceptee Circulator
Date       Facility     Entries By Name
2021-09-10 Cape Fear    5       DI           10:01       <NA>       <NA>         KL
                                KL           09:50       <NA>       <NA>         DI
                                LOA          09:30       <NA>       <NA>         WH
                                SR           09:48       <NA>       <NA>         JR
                                WH           11:52       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
2021-09-11 Facility Two 2       AA           10:01       <NA>       <NA>         ZZ
                                DI           11:58       <NA>       <NA>         KL
```

Comment: Thank you; This is really close. But It total entries for "Cape Fear" should be 6 as "JR" entered the facility as "Circulator".

Comment: So "Entries" should be the number of unique names in all four columns (By Name, Preceptor, Preceptee and Circulator)?

Comment: Yes. The total of unique names across all four columns.

Comment: OK. In your "Desired Output", do you actually need `Begin Time` as a column? Also, would it be sufficient to have a new column named `Unique Names` instead of the four columns (By Name, Preceptor, Preceptee and Circulator), with 6 rows, one for each unique name?

Comment: I would need the "Begin TIme" for further analysis on this data as there are multiple conditions I need to put once this data is sorted. Yes, it would be sufficient to have a new column.

Comment: OK, understood. Please see my updated answer for what I think will do what you want.